# Laravel Query Join and Count

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to replicate the following sql query into laravel controller with no luck. The query works fine as a direct mysql query so there is issue with the data but the complexity is baffling me with the laravel query builder. I have tried to use the 'Raw()' function and a variable in the controller but this is still not returning data from the query. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT * 
 FROM (SELECT * from figures 
) t2
  left join 
( SELECT
    figure_id, 
    SUM(IF(trade='1', trade, 0)) as trades,
    SUM(IF(sale='1', sale, 0)) as sales
FROM userfigures
GROUP BY figure_id ) t1
ON (t1.figure_id = t2.id)
```

raw command

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * from figures) t2 left join ( SELECT figure_id, SUM(IF(trade='1', trade, 0)) as trades, SUM(IF(sale='1', sale, 0)) as sales FROM userfigures GROUP BY figure_id ) t1 ON (t1.figure_id = t2.id)";
   $sellers = userfigures::Raw($sql)->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

```
DB::table('figures as t1')
  ->leftJoin(DB::table('userfigures as t2')
  ->select('figure_id',
           DB::raw("SUM(IF(trade = '1', trade, 0)) AS trades"), 
           DB::raw("SUM(IF(sale = '1', sale, 0)) AS sales")
  )
  ->groupBy('figure_id'), 't1.figure_id', 't2.id')
  ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried the code and i get the following error which I cant get past after a bit of tinkering. "Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be converted to string" Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I have found a solution, but would love to learn the solution above as this is the modern was to do the query alirezadp10.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DB::select` instead of `userfigures::Raw` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/database#running-queries

Comment: I am working through this method as I want to lear both methods, initially with the code above I get an error: "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column". I updated the code to
```
$sellers = DB::select($sql)->get();
```
I get an intellisense error: Expected type 'object'. Found 'array'. in VScode and "Call to a member function get() on array" in the browser.
I have tried "$sellers2 = (array) $sellers;" under the line above but get an output of the query to the view. 

(I feel guilty asking questions here and dont want to appear like I just want the answer!)

Comment: I've got this working, for some reason having the first word "SELECT" written in capitals was causing an error, changed it to lowercase it worked! and then changed it to uppercase. Very random (suspect it was me in some way) Your code is a solution. Many thanks.

Comment: This is the code that works for this type of query:

`code
 $sellers1 = userfigures::select( 'figures.*', 'userfigures.figure_id', DB::raw('SUM(IF(trade="1", trade, 0)) as trades'), DB::raw('SUM(IF(sale="1", sale, 0)) as sales'))
     ->rightJoin('figures', 'figures.id', '=', 'userfigures.figure_id')
    // ->where('analytics.date', Carbon::today()->toDateString())
     ->groupBy('figures.id', 'userfigures.figure_id') 
     ->paginate(10);
`

Thanks for helping me get to the right code based on your help AndreiXwe